# Why is xcode giving me a "method not found" error?

Tags: iphone, xcode, methods, call

I have an object called `Shot` which is a subclass of `UIIMageView`.

```
//  Shot.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Shot : UIImageView {
    CGPoint position; 
}
- (void)SetShot:(CGPoint *)point;
@end


//  Shot.m


#import "Shot.h"


@implementation Shot

- (void)SetShot:(CGPoint *)point;
{
    position.x = point->x;
    position.y = point->y;

}

@end
```

When I try to call the `SetShot` method, xcode gives me this warning:

> method -SetShot not found(return type defaults to id)

Here is the call:

```
//CustomImageView.m
#import "CustomImageView.h"

@class Shot;
@implementation CustomImageView

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
}


-(void) setInteraction
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    Shot *shot;

    [shot SetShot:point];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

When I run the program, I get a fatal error when the method is called. Why is that?

Comment: I highly recommend that you accept Bavarious's well explained answer.

Answer (score 5):

There are three problems in your code. Firstly, you need to import Shot.h in your CustomImageView.m implementation file:

```
#import "Shot.h"
```

instead of simply forward-declaring the `Shot` class:

```
@class Shot;
```

When the compiler sees a forward declaration, it becomes aware of the existence of that class but doesn’t yet know its attributes, declared properties, or methods — in particular, it doesn’t know that `Shot` has a `-SetPoint:` instance method.

Secondly, you’re **not** creating an instance of `Shot`:

```
Shot *shot;
[shot SetShot:point];
```

This only declares that `shot` is a pointer to `Shot` but there’s no allocation/initialisation. You should create an object, i.e.:

```
Shot *shot = [[Shot alloc] init];
```

then use it:

```
[shot SetShot:point];
```

and, when you don’t need it any longer, release it:

```
[shot release];
```

Although it’s not clear what’s the benefit of creating a shot, setting its point, and then releasing it. Unless your code is a contrived example, you might want to rethink this behaviour.

Also, your `-SetPoint:` method has a pointer to `CGPoint` parameter but you’re passing a `CGPoint` value (i.e., not a pointer) argument:

```
// point is not a pointer!
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
Shot *shot;
[shot SetShot:point];
```

I suggest you drop the pointer altogether, i.e.:

```
- (void)SetShot:(CGPoint)point;
{
    position = point;    
}
```

and maybe use a [declared property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) instead of a manually implemented setter method.

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that... my bad. I thought you had to assign it that way.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Your response has helped me so much!

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
#import "Shot.h"
```

instead of:

```
@class Shot;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not created an instance of `Shot`; you have only created a pointer with:

```
Shot *shot;
```

You must allocate and initialize it:

```
Shot *shot = [[Shot alloc] init];
```

At some point you must import the header file `Shot.h` as well.

Comment: anon's answer is the immediate problem, but this is also a significant bug.